# Using absolute value to solve an equation.

Tags: linear-algebra

I am required to have two answers to this problem:

A 'Larger Number' and a 'Smaller Number'.

I know that I have half of the question correct (The 'Larger Number' answer). But I do not know how to find the second answer (The 'Smaller Number'). HELP!

> $$\big|a-5 \big|=\frac{4}{5}$$
>
> Solve for $a$

Again...I know the 'Larger Number' answer is $a=\frac{19}{3}$

Please help me find the 'Smaller Number' answer.
I know that NO SOLUTION is not the answer.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE - please refrain from leaving your personal details in a question. This is for your own safety. :)

Answer (score 4):

The two solutions are $a-5=\frac{4}{5}$ and $-(a-5)=5-a=\frac{4}{5}$.

Comment: More explicitly, $a=\frac{4}{5}+5 = \frac{4}{5}+\frac{25}{5}=\frac{29}{5}$ and $a=5-\frac{4}{5} = \frac{25}{5}-\frac{4}{5}=\frac{21}{5}$

Comment: Hi..Thanks for responding!

Comment: I know that one of the answers...The Larger Number= a=19/3
so I'm not sure if your answer is right? What would the Smaller Number be, and how can I find that answer?